# Attached debugger to Jest run does not work; all tests crash with JSX errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

When following these instructions (https://jestjs.io/docs/en/troubleshooting) to use an interactive debugger with Jest, I am unable to get the specs to run the same way they do for me when I run them with **yarn**.

basically, my expected result should something like this

(when run with Yarn)

```
$ yarn test --watchAll --coverage
 PASS  src/components/blurb_box.test.js (5.039s)
 PASS  src/components/logo_container.test.js (5.04s)
 PASS  src/reducers/logo_reducer.test.js
  ...
 FAIL  src/components/app_container.test.js (5.514s)
  ...

 PASS  src/components/momeas_logo_inner.test.js
 PASS  src/components/marble.test.js
 PASS  src/components/App.test.js
 PASS  src/components/rings.test.js
 PASS  src/actions/index.test.js
 PASS  src/trig.test.js
 PASS  src/reducers/marbles_reducer.test.js
 PASS  src/reducers/focused_reducer.test.js
 PASS  src/parse_url_utils.test.js
 PASS  src/behaviors/does_touch_something_else.test.js
-------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File                           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files                      |    68.85 |    62.96 |    58.46 |     69.2 |                   |
 src                           |     90.2 |    82.14 |      100 |    91.67 |                   |
  constants.js                 |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  index.js                     |        0 |        0 |      100 |        0 |       15,17,19,30 |
  parse_url_utils.js           |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  settings.js                  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  trig.js                      |    95.24 |       95 |      100 |      100 |                51 |
 src/actions                   |    57.14 |      100 |       40 |    57.14 |                   |
  index.js                     |    57.14 |      100 |       40 |    57.14 |... 81,106,108,112 |
 src/behaviors                 |    92.86 |       75 |      100 |    92.86 |                   |
  does_touch_something_else.js |    92.86 |       75 |      100 |    92.86 |                33 |
 src/components                |    57.26 |    32.35 |     42.5 |    57.89 |                   |
  App.jsx                      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  app_container.js             |    64.71 |       50 |    42.11 |       64 |... 98,215,229,230 |
  blurb_box.js                 |       75 |        0 |       50 |       75 |                 7 |
  logo_container.js            |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  marble.js                    |    12.12 |        0 |        0 |     12.9 |... 67,171,175,178 |
  momeas_logo_inner.js         |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  rings.js                     |    88.24 |       75 |       60 |    88.24 |             55,60 |
 src/reducers                  |    73.17 |    93.33 |       80 |     72.5 |                   |
  focused_reducer.js           |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  logo_reducer.js              |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
  marbles_reducer.js           |       50 |       80 |    66.67 |       50 |... 72,73,75,76,78 |
-------------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|

Test Suites: 1 failed, 13 passed, 14 total
Tests:       1 failed, 60 passed, 61 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.937s
Ran all test suites.
```

basically I should see 1 failed test and 13 passing ones.

Instead, when I run 
`node --inspect-brk node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand` to be able to attach the interactive debugger to my jest run, I get all these errors related parse errors.

I am able to successfully go to `chrome://inspect` and actually attach the debugger, which in turn triggers the test run itself

then pretty much ALL my tests fail, with these kinds of errors (partial results shown)

```
$ node --inspect-brk node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand 
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/427ca26e-78cd-42c6-8aff-28f07327f16b
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
 FAIL  src/reducers/focused_reducer.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /Users/jason/Work/Momeas Interactive/momeas_com/momeas_com3/client/src/reducers/focused_reducer.test.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import React from 'react';
                                                                                                    ^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)

 FAIL  src/reducers/marbles_reducer.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /Users/jason/Work/Momeas Interactive/momeas_com/momeas_com3/client/src/reducers/marbles_reducer.test.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import React from 'react';
                                                                                                    ^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)

 FAIL  src/reducers/logo_reducer.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /Users/jason/Work/Momeas Interactive/momeas_com/momeas_com3/client/src/reducers/logo_reducer.test.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import React from 'react';
                                                                                                    ^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)

 FAIL  src/parse_url_utils.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /Users/jason/Work/Momeas Interactive/momeas_com/momeas_com3/client/src/parse_url_utils.test.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import React from 'react';
                                                                                                    ^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)

 FAIL  src/actions/index.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /Users/jason/Work/Momeas Interactive/momeas_com/momeas_com3/client/src/actions/index.test.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import React from 'react';
                                                                                                    ^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)

 FAIL  src/behaviors/does_touch_something_else.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /Users/jason/Work/Momeas Interactive/momeas_com/momeas_com3/client/src/behaviors/does_touch_something_else.test.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import doesTouchSomethingElse from './does_touch_something_else';
                                                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)

 FAIL  src/components/blurb_box.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    SyntaxError: /Users/jason/Work/Momeas Interactive/momeas_com/momeas_com3/client/src/components/blurb_box.test.js: Unexpected token (15:14)

      13 |   it('able to shallow render', () => {
      14 |     expect(
    > 15 |       shallow(<BlurbBox />).find('div.blurb').length
         |               ^
      16 |     ).toBe(1)
      17 |   })
      18 | })

      at Parser.raise (node_modules/babel-jest/node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/location.js:41:63)

 FAIL  src/components/logo_container.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /Users/jason/Work/Momeas Interactive/momeas_com/momeas_com3/client/src/components/logo_container.test.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import React from 'react';
                                                                                                    ^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
```

My client/package.json file is

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@dr-kobros/react-webfont-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "deep-freeze": "^0.0.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "query-string": "^6.9.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1",
    "react-thunk": "^1.0.0",
    "react-use": "^13.12.2",
    "reactstrap": "^8.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "styled-components": "^4.3.2",
    "thunk": "^0.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "cypress": "cypress open",
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint ."
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/dom": "^6.10.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "cypress": "^3.8.0",
    "fetch": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "coverageReporters": [
      "html",
      "text"
    ]
  }
}
```

my `client/.bablerc.json` file is this, but the presence or absence of this bablerc file has no affect on the errors

```
{ "presets":["react","es2015","stage-1"] }
```